# Flutter relative top and right of positioned in stack

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, position, scale

I am creating drag images on left side of the screen, while there is model on right side of the screen. The images can be dragged onto the model in 2 areas, and should remain there relative to model. The top and right are placed so those to areas are on correct position.
What I'm trying to achieve is to scale top and right parameters of Positioned widget, but after trying a lot of things, i have failed. As far as i see, the Stack scales the first element but the rest same the same.
The code is here:

```
Stack(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            "assets/draggable/model.png",
            width: 335 *
                (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                    MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) /
                1010,
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 385 *
                ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) /
                    1010),
            right: 66 *
                (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                    MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) /
                1010,
            child: DragTarget<String>(
                builder: (
                  BuildContext context,
                  List<dynamic> accepted,
                  List<dynamic> rejected,
                ) {
                  return Image.asset(
                    myImage2,
                    width: 205 *
                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                          MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) /
                      1010,
                  );
                },
                onAccept: (String data) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (data.split("/")[2].contains("d")) {
                      myImage2 = data;
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 185 *
                ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) /
                    1010),
            right: 60 *
                (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                    MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) /
                1010,
            child: DragTarget<String>(
              builder: (
                BuildContext context,
                List<dynamic> accepted,
                List<dynamic> rejected,
              ) {
                return Image.asset(
                  myImage,
                  width: 216 *
                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                          MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) /
                      1010,
                );
              },
              onAccept: (String data) {
                setState(() {
                  if (data.split("/")[2].contains("c")) {
                    myImage = data;
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

PS: scaling this way works perfectly for width and right but the top parameter is bad. Also the 1010 and is height of screen i measured the width,top and right with, so I'm scaling it.

Comment: *"but the top parameter is bad."* - how do you know it is bad? what actually do you want to achieve? some image maybe?

Comment: @pskink yes, i need to drag image on another image, and then image overlays it. There are 2 types, at 2 different positions. When scalling, the right position scales and the images remains on the position in should, but top doesn't so whole dragged image goes down a bit, for some reason.

Comment: i dont think i can work if you use those "magic" dividers like `1010`

Comment: @pskink i measured it on screen that has height of 1010, and the right of 66 is if the screen is 1010 height. So i scale down or up depending on the size of screen. It works fine for right, it scales it perfectly, but it does not scale it verticaly(top)

Comment: Can you include a visual representation(image) that will describe your desire output?

Comment: @pskink yes, exactly that

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes i can, here are 2 pictures
https://imgur.com/a/AKu6Iuo
https://imgur.com/a/wWZSBpT

Comment: @pskink thank you, i will try it out now

Comment: @pskink thank you very much, this is exactly what i needed! I just need to modify it now for multple children.

Comment: @pskink it gives error when using layout builder inside Row that has space between :(

Comment: @pskink i have row that has mainAxisAlignment on space between, left side has clothes to be dragged, right side has model to be dressed up. And the model doesn't render if i put it in LayoutBuilder

Comment: @pskink yes, that doesn't work, throws exceptions. I tried it on Chrome and Linux.

Comment: *"yes, that doesn't work, throws exceptions"* - i dont see any exceptions, tried on linux: `Flutter 2.11.0-0.1.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b101bfe32f (6 weeks ago) • 2022-02-16 07:36:54 -0800
Engine • revision e355993572
Tools • Dart 2.17.0 (build 2.17.0-69.2.beta) • DevTools 2.10.0-dev.1
`

Comment: @pskink it works when i upgrade. thanks

Comment: ??? what flutter version did you have then? < 2.0? ;-)

Comment: @pskink probably, i installed it long ago :/